# How to show the actual value of a signature using the RSA library in Python?

Tags: python, rsa, digital-signature

I'm using the [RSA library](https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/index.html) to check a digital signature using the Public Key as follows:

```
rsa.verify(message, sig, key)
```

The function works as expected however, for incorrect cases the library prints out

```
rsa.pkcs1.VerificationError: Verification failed
```

I want to see the actual calculated value, so that I can compare it to the expected value. Is there a way to print that without tweaking the internals of the library?

Comment: the [`verify()`](https://github.com/sybrenstuvel/python-rsa/blob/version-3.4.2/rsa/pkcs1.py#L286) method isn't that complicated, you could simply copy and change it the way you need.

Comment: I understand, I didn't want to change the library though because that would require other users to use my modified version of the library.

Comment: Maybe, I can just make my own function based on their verify().

Comment: Yes, that's what I ment by copying the functions code, modifying the library directly would be a bad Idea. The alternative would be to catch the error and extract the values from the callstack (using `inspect.stack()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `verify()` method as a template:

```
from rsa import common, core, transform

keylength = common.byte_size(base)
decrypted = core.decrypt_int(sig, exp, base)
clearsig = transform.int2bytes(decrypted, keylength)
```

This is with the assumption that your signature is given as `sig`, the modulus and exp of the public key are `base` and `exp` respectively.

Last thing to note is that your hash might include padding in the beginning. As I used SHA-256, I had to look at the last 32 bytes of `clearsig`.

Comment: It seems you've removed the padding part. Proper padding is very important for the security of RSA signatures. You might have actually completely subverted RSA signatures by doing this. Although, I'm not absolutely sure.